# google charts: timeline Scale

Tags: javascript, charts, timeline, pygooglechart

I use angular 6. In google chart timeline, how i can set the scale of the timeline to show just weeks or month, not show the day.

I set my graph like that :

Basegraph service

```
declare var google: any;

export class GoogleChartsBaseService {
  constructor() { 
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':["timeline"], 'language': 'fr'});
  }

  protected buildChart(data: any[], chartFunc: any, options: any) : void {
    var func = (chartFunc, options) => {
      var datatable = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
      chartFunc().draw(datatable, options);
    };   
    var callback = () => func(chartFunc, options);
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(callback);
  }

}
```

Timeline service

```
    import { GoogleChartsBaseService } from './google-charts-base.service';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { GanttChartConfig } from './../models/GanttChartConfig.model';

    declare var google: any;

    @Injectable()
    export class GoogleGanttChartService extends GoogleChartsBaseService {

      constructor() { super(); }

      public BuildPieChart(elementId: string, data: any[], config: GanttChartConfig) : void {  
        var chartFunc = () => { return new google.visualization.Timeline(document.getElementById(elementId)); };

     var rowHeight = 41;
        var chartHeight = data.length * rowHeight + 50;

    var options = {
            traitement: config.traitement,
                  datedebut: config.datedebut,
            datefin: config.datefin,
            chartArea:{},
            height: chartHeight
        };
           this.buildChart(data, chartFunc, options);
  }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set hAxis.

```
var options = {
        traitement: config.traitement,
              datedebut: config.datedebut,
        datefin: config.datefin,
        chartArea:{},
        height: chartHeight,


hAxis: {
  format: 'dd MMMM yyyy',

}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.